# Bad value for type byte -postgres, spring, JPA

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I want to store an entity in Postgres with this schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ingredient
(
    id   VARCHAR(4)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
```

This is the Java model

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC, force = true)
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    private final String id;
    private final String name;

    private final Type type;

    public enum Type {
        WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
    }
}
```

Here is the code

```
@Profile("!prod")
@Configuration
public class DevelopmentConfig {
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner dataLoader(
            IngredientRepository ingredientRepo,
    ) {
        return args -> {
            Ingredient flourTortilla = new Ingredient(
                    "FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP);
            ingredientRepo.save(flourTortilla);
            
        };
    }
}
```

I receive this error - **Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not extract column [3] from JDBC ResultSet [Bad value for type byte : WRAP]**

**Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type byte : WRAP
**

Any advice is appreciated.

I have tried research this error but no answer was found, I have tried to define the column data type but it still not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate is trying to convert the enum to a byte type **by default**, but the value of the enum is a string, not a byte, so you need to specify that you want the enum to be persisted as a String, using `@Enumerated`:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC, force = true)
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    private final String id;
    private final String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private final Type type;

    public enum Type {
        WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
    }
}
```

Read more: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-enum-mappings/

Answer (score 5):

The most probable issue is that Spring, by default, stores Enums using their ordinal value (numeric) rather than their String value. You could attempt the following:

```
private final String name;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private final Type type;
```

Comment: Besides that, I had to add a @NoArgsConstructor annotation and type my enum values lowercased. (I'm using Postgres, maybe that's why I had to lowercase them)